# Unpermitted parameters & unable to display nested fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, ruby-on-rails-5, fields-for

I am building simple ROR app which has survey question and answers. Survey is generated using scaffolding method while question and answer are model only.

**Survey.rb**

```
class Survey < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :questions
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, allow_destroy: true
 validates :name, presence: true
end
```

**Question.rb**

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :survey
 has_many :answers
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
 validates :question_content, presence: true
end
```

**Answer.rb**

```
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :question
end
```

**survey_controller.rb**

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_survey, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
 @surveys = Survey.all
end

def show
 @survey= Survey.find(params[:id])
end

def new
 @survey = Survey.new
 @questions = @survey.questions.new
 @answers = @questions.answers.new
end

def edit
end

def create
 @survey = Survey.new(survey_params)
 Survey.create(survey_params)
 respond_to do |format|
  if @survey.save
    format.html { redirect_to @survey, notice: 'Survey was successfully  created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @survey }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @survey.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @survey.update(survey_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @survey, notice: 'Survey was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @survey }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @survey.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def destroy
@survey.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to surveys_url, notice: 'Survey was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end

private
def set_survey
  @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
end

def survey_params
  params.require(:survey).permit(:name, questions_attributes: [:id, :question_content], answers_attributes: [:id, :answer_content, :answer_type])
end
end
```

**Survey form partial**

```
<%= form_for(@survey) do |form| %>
<% if survey.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(survey.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this survey from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% survey.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
<%= form.label :name %>
<%= form.text_field :name, id: :survey_name %>
</div>

<%= form.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
<fieldset>
  <%= builder.label :question_content, "Question" %><br/>
  <%= builder.text_area :question_content %><br/>
  <%= form.fields_for :answers do |f| %>
    <fieldset>
        <%= f.text_area :answer_type %>
        <%= f.text_area :answer_content %><br/>
    </fieldset>
</fieldset>
<% end %>
<%end %>


<div class="actions">
<%= form.submit %>
</div>
```

I want to implement question and answer in single page i.e survey. Any help will appreciated.

Problem : Unable to save answers_attributes to database but Question attributes work perfectly fine. I am probably making mistake somewhere in controller not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the way you're building the answer fields, so that they're referenced as fields_for `questions`, not `surveys`. Try changing this piece of code:

```
<%= form.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
<fieldset>
  <%= builder.label :question_content, "Question" %><br/>
  <%= builder.text_area :question_content %><br/>
  <%= form.fields_for :answers do |f| %>
    <fieldset>
        <%= f.text_area :answer_type %>
        <%= f.text_area :answer_content %><br/>
    </fieldset>
</fieldset>
<% end %>
<%end %>
```

to this:

```
<%= form.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
  <fieldset>
    <%= builder.label :question_content, "Question" %><br/>
    <%= builder.text_area :question_content %><br/>
    <%= builder.fields_for :answers do |f| %>
      <fieldset>
        <%= f.text_area :answer_type %>
        <%= f.text_area :answer_content %><br/>
      </fieldset>
    <% end %>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

(Note: the meaningful change is changing `form.fields_for` to `builder.fields_for`)

Comment: Hello Derek, Adding builder reference to answer doesn't display any fields in front end